# It seems that my row ignores my container padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, containers

The issue is on this page: http://haagmedia.dk/klf/holdet.php

The issue is that the grey box/row you see on the page above, is somehow ignoring my container, and I tried to figure out this issue for quite a while now, and I can't  break the code. 
I want the grey box to align on the sides, with the image above and the button below. I dont know if this other issue related to the same thing aswell, but when I scale down the page to mobile size, the grey box floats to the right, where it should be centered?

long question I know - here are the codes related to the box and the container.
Your help would mean a lot

HTML

```
<div class="conhold container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="hvad1 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <h4>SERIE 4, HERRESENIOR</h4>
            </div>    
        </div>


        <div class="hold row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/hold.png" alt="holdbillede">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="tekst1 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="knap1-1 row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
                    <a href="kontakt.php" class="knaplink hvr-fade" alt="link til medlemskab">BLIV MEDLEM I KLUBBEN</a>
                </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

CSS

```
.tekst1 {
    background-color: #A4ABB0;
    height: 200px;
}

@media(max-width: 1000px) {
    .conhold {
        padding-left: 30px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap styles are causing the problem.

Your elements have a `padding-left: 15px` and `padding-right: 15px`.

[image]

Override or remove them, and all three items align evenly in the column.

---

In terms of centering, just balance out your rule:

```
@media(max-width: 1000px) {
    .conhold {
        padding-left: 30px;
    }
}
```

... *add `padding-right: 30px`*.

Comment: The last part works for me - the centering part! dumb of me not to notice, but thanks! But I still got problems with the 1st part though... If I override/remove my padding, then it is my image and button which expands - I want the grey row/box to shrink so it gets the same width as the image and the button, and not the other way around! - hope you guys can help me further!

Comment: Then add `padding-left: 15px` and `padding-right: 15px` to the gray box parent div.

Comment: It worked! you are a true champ, thanks a lot! I am still kind a new and learning, so thanks for the help... Is there another way to do this, so I dont have to give the parent div 15px padding every time? because to me, it seems kind a weird, that the row ignored the container padding in the first place...

Comment: It is unusual... in pure CSS. But since you're working with Bootstrap, there are thousands of possible rules that may cause a conflict.

Comment: Didn't knew about that either - haha... but there you go! thanks again